# No such file or director db_config.php

Tags: php

I received that error when i tried to run fetch_all_persons.php . Im pretty sure db_config.php and fetch are in the same folder on my hosting service. I checked everything but couldn't find it. Is there anyone? Thank you.

> Warning: require_once(/home/u654244246/domains/somedomain.com/public_html/Test/db.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u654244246/domains/somedomain.com/public_html/Test/fetch_all_persons.php on line 7

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/u654244246/domains/somedomain.com/public_html/Test/db.config.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/u654244246/domains/somedomain.com/public_html/Test/fetch_all_persons.php on line 7

db_config.php file:

```
<?php 
define('DB_DATABASE', "u654244246_dbSwift"); 
define('DB_USER', "u654244246_admin"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', "123456789"); 
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); ?>
```

fetch_all_persons.php file :

```
<?php  error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');  
$response = array(); 
require_once __DIR__ . '/db.config.php';  
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); 
if(!$connection){     
die("Connection error : " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}  
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM persons"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQuery);  
// If there is at least 1 data  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){     
$response["persons"] = array();     
// fetch every data on table one by one     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){     
    $persons = array();         
$persons['person_id'] = $row['person_id'];    
     $persons['person_name'] = $row['person_name'];  
       $persons['person_phone'] = $row['person_phone'];       
   array_push($response["persons"], $persons);     
}     
$response["success"] = 1;     
echo json_encode($response); 
}else {     
$response["success"] = 0;   
  $response["message"] = "Required field( ds) is missing";   
  echo json_encode($response); } mysqli_close($connection); ?>
```

Comment: It's not the db config file's content you need to check, but the code that wants to ise said file.

Comment: `pretty sure` isn't really very useful. Actually checking and being certain would be better. Programming doesn't exactly thrive on ambiguity :-)

Comment: Anyway if I've understood the error (although i dont think you posted all of it!) what you really need to check is what path `__DIR__ . '/db.config.php';` generates and whether that's correct.

Comment: I said pretty sure because i checked the folder on my hosting and checked MySQL db. I am sorry about that if i not being clearer. I'll pay attention to that. And also thanks for the answer im checking the path.

Comment: The error seems clear that public_html/Test/db.config.php doesn't exist in your hosting

Comment: Is it `db_config.php` or `db.config.php`? You've used both versions with your question and that might as well be the problem.

Comment: Your right that was the problem,  i changed it and its gone. Thank you so much :)